# Unregistering and uninstalling a Context menu driver

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing a software removal program, and want to uninstall a context menu driver. Just unregistering the driver while Windows File Explorer is open fails when trying to unregister the dll. Closing file explorer first and then running the program does not always work either.

Here is the unregister code I am using now:

```
HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibraryW(szDllPath);

if (hLib == NULL)
{
    DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    szError.Format(_T("\nWindows could not load library %s due to %s"),szDllName,getLastWinError(dwErrorCode));
    return false;            
}

typedef HRESULT (CALLBACK *HCRET)(void);
HCRET lpfnDllRegisterServer;

// Find the entry point
lpfnDllRegisterServer = (HCRET)GetProcAddress(hLib, "DllUnregisterServer");



if (lpfnDllRegisterServer == NULL)
{
    szError = NEWLINE;
    szError = ERR_PROCEDURE_ADDRESS;
    return false;            
}

// Call the function by function pointer..
if (FAILED((*lpfnDllRegisterServer)()))            
{   
    szError.Format(_T("\nWindows could not unregister context menu driver %s!"),szDllName);
    return false;            
}

FreeLibrary(hLib);
```

What is the best way to go about this? It seems that even if the dll is unregistered by just deleting the relevant registry keys, File Explorer still will not let go of it.

Comment: Have you tried running `Regsvr32.exe /u <DLL>` manually? What is the error code?

Comment: Yes. After further testing the problem seems not to be in the actual unregistering the dll. The above code seems to do that. But even if File Explorer is closed, Windows will still not allow deletion of it. The only way to delete it is to reboot the computer, and then delete it. I am making an uninstaller and need to be able to delete those files.